# Rebase git tree keeping revert references

Tags: git, rebase, git-revert, commit-message

I have a couple of branches with many commits (~20-30) and some of them revert earlier commits from the same branch.

I now need to rebase those branches on current HEAD but I want to keep the revert commits, at least for now. (The branch is a port from another tree so it is valuable to see what is NOT used)
Those commits usually have a message like "This reverts `<SHA>`" which will become invalid after the rebase.

Is there any option or tool to do the rebase but update the revert commit messages while doing so in a way so that they reference the new (rebased) commits?

Example history:

- SHA0 Old HEAD
- SHA1 Add Foo
- SHA2 Add Bar
- SHA3 Revert "Add Foo"\n\n This reverts SHA1

Should become:

- SHA10 New HEAD
- SHA11 Add Foo
- SHA12 Add Bar
- SHA13 Revert "Add Foo"\n\n This reverts SHA11

Comment: Not really, no - though `git filter-repo` does this particular trick, so if you can figure out how to do a rebase with filter-repo, that would get you there.